# Custom layer tensorflow gets error ‘customlayer’ object has no attribute ‘layers’

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I’ve made a custom layer with the class method and when I’m trying to call the class it shows this error message :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-143-9ad907fef5b1> in <module>
----> 1 model.layers()

AttributeError: 'lane_detection_network' object has no attribute 'layers'
```

the code is here:

```
class lane_detection_network(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(lane_detection_network, self).__init__()

        self.resizing = resize_layer(3, 128)

        #feature extraction
        self.layer1 = hourglass_block(128, 128)
        self.layer2 = hourglass_block(128, 128)

    def call(self, inputs):
        #feature extraction
        out = self.resizing(inputs)
        result1, out = self.layer1(out)
        result2, out = self.layer2(out)      

        return [result1, result2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is because `tf.Module` is a [very basic class](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Module) - it does not have `layers`. Also, you have not explicitly set them.

Is there a reason you are not using Keras? Otherwise, [this TF guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models) demonstrates exactly how to achieve what you want. Make sure you know the difference between a `Layer` and a `Model` and then it should be straightforward to get the desired result.